# Can I authenticate SMTP using SwiftMailer without sending an email

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

I am trying to verify login credentials with SwiftMailer in Laravel.  I need to verify the login credentials to an SMTP server without actually sending the email.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
$client = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($smtpServer, $smtpPort, 'ssl');
$client->setUsername($this->smtpUser);
$client->setPassword($this->smtpPass);
$client->authenticate();
```

There is no `authenticate()` method on the `Swift_SmtpTransport` but it would be great if there was something similar I could use.

I can't find a suitable function in the source: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php

Is there a way to just try and verify authentication on an SMTP server using SwiftMailer without having to send the email?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From their [manual](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html):

> If you need to know early whether or not authentication has failed and
>   an Exception is going to be thrown, call the `start()` method on the
>   created Transport.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. It kind of threw me off that `start()` will return true if you don't set a username and password and just call `$client->start()` with a valid SMTP server and encryption type.  When I tried to put in the username and password it did require them to be right though.